# Help me understand XOR gate with diode logic

Tags: diodes, logic-gates, bridge-rectifier

I'm generally a pretty smart person, but for some reason I can't get my head wrapped around this one.

A little background - 
I have performed this function before using two diodes and two SPDT relays. It works fine, but is bulky and wastes some money. 
I did it with logic gates and one SPST relay. That was super fun and a learning experience. It worked, but didn't last long.

I have seen it written that the same thing can be done with either:
A - a rectifier bridge, or;
B - a rectifier and a some resistors

If I am using the correct specs for the components, either option would be smaller and cheaper and just as robust as the relay and diode method.
And, if I am reading the specs on the components right the relay isn't even needed.

I have no problem spending a few bucks to build something and letting the magic smoke out of some components and finding out it won't work. 
What I do have a problem with is the fact that I just do not see how this works?

Which of these is correct?
Can you please help me understand how this would work?
Am I right that the components can be spec'd heavy enough to leave the relay out?
Are the resistors necessary, and if so how do you calculate the required values?

If this can really be done with a $1.28 rectifier rated at 100V, 20A that would save a lot of hassle and space. But, I really just want to understand why and how?!

It's easy to see how you would get power to the LED when either input high, but how does the output circuit get back to ground?
What causes it to not get power when both inputs are high?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO80zd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have spent quite a bit of time researching this and just can't manage to explain it to myself...

(BTW - please ignore the fact that the LED doesn't have a protective resistor, this is just for the purpose of me understanding how this works, not an actual design.

Thank you!

EDITS made as suggested...

Comment: And after reading my question I think I just explained to myself why you need the resistors. They are the ground path for the output circuit, correct? If that's true, then I don't see how version A would work at all...

Comment: And I still don't get why both inputs being high would shut down the output (output low)?

Comment: Or maybe both inputs being high would just not allow the output circuit to return to ground? But, why not?

Comment: *"Which of these is correct?"* There is no way to know since you haven't specified what this circuit is supposed to do.  You refer to "this" function in the second paragraph, but never defined it!  This really should have been obvious.

Comment: Input A and B need to be defined in the Off position as 0V open cct or 0V and 0 Ohms to Gnd. This makes a difference.

Comment: @ Olin Lathrop - That's why I added a logic diagram labeled "desired function" in the schematic. It's basically an XOR gate (that can survive the nasty noisy dirty electrical environment in a vehicle electrical system).

Comment: @ Tony Stewart - they would be 0V open circuit when in the Off position. (I have now added that info to the schematic).

Comment: XOR gate should never be open circuit on input (floating) but  with  Diode bridge both R's to ground are needed for cathode return current. e.g. (12(sources)-1.3(bridge)-3.1V(white)/15mA= ~500

Comment: I can clearly see that is going to be another in the latest long string of questions that I end up deleting without getting an answer. I don't understand all of the constant down voting. I'm trying to understand how / why something in the EE realm works and I thought that's what this forum was for?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Does that apply to this type of "hardware logic gate"? I am not going to use an actual logic gate, that was just to demonstrate how I want the circuit to work.

Comment: Users forget how to specify inputs and outputs get down voted often by others ( not me)  Voltage and impedance are needed for any switch, including diode or switch sources......yes.. the only problem with open switch and current limit R is you apply power across R's even when both inputs ON  for LED OFF

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 So, if I understanding you correctly that is another reason the resistors are needed - to pull the inputs to the bridge low when power is not present?

Comment: Yes but they get hot if too small IF either input is on

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 - would there be such a thing as "too big"? How would you calculated what would be appropriate?

Comment: Ohm's Law and a better design would help as  Resistor Diode Logic is like stone age.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 What is the purpose of over complicating something if it is robust and works? As I stated in the question I have done this other ways in the past, but this will save a little money and a LOT of space.

Comment: It neither saves money , space nor power.. Any time you wish to design anything. start with input , functions, and output power for minimum specs.. Dont decide that a bridge must be the cheapest way then find out you are burning out R1,R2 and waste time

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 After doing more research and calculating on my own I agree. But I am still very glad I asked this question as I now understand how this would work and that was actually the point. I came across these circuits while searching for something and just didn't understand the theory behind it. I don't know how I could have been so daft as to not get it, but I didn't. And now I do. And that alone is well worth any time and effort I put into searching and asking!

Comment: Glad you appreciate the effort I made to draw schematic and show current in example and why it is so inefficient for LEDs, but XOR  logic . The transformer source vs.  a switched DC source makes a difference. WHich is why SMPS use push pull half bridge (SPDT) and others SPST open switch depends on energy transformed or stored

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I do appreciate it. I appreciate everyone that took their time to respond! My main motivation for doing projects like this is learning. It was a very tempting solution as it seemed to eliminate additional components like relays and additional separate power lines, but it was fools gold. But the knowledge I gained is very real.

Comment: Diode bridge only works well as XOR function when 0V is also low R source not switched open like your scenario, but if your source has SPDT to V+,0V then no R1, R2 needed , just shared Series R in LED. make sense?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yes, makes sense, Thanks for the knowledge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the circuit does is to light the led when the voltages are different. The xor function that you mention.

If both voltages are 0v no current flows.  If both are at 12v no current flows also. But if one is 12v and the other is 0v current will pass through the led. 
The rectifier is needed if you don't mind which one is up and which down. 
You could use two led in anti-parallel, one will light in each case.

The fact that you have used a CC source  symbol leads to confusion. It only makes sense if voltages can vary.

Hope this will help you!

Edit: it is digital electronics, the symbol should have been a **square wave source**.

Comment: The led only lights when current passes through it. If both ends of the led are at 12v no difference of potential exists so no current flow. In fact it's the same case that 0v-0v

Comment: wow, I feel pretty stupid now. That makes perfect sense...

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer and ask a new one about the diode specs. Thanks!

Comment: The Led wont pass much current unless the R1,R2 consume 2x~3x power when both inputs at 12V and LED is OFF

Answer (score 1):

> I have no problem spending a few bucks to build something and letting
>   the magic smoke out of some components and finding out it won't work.
>   What I do have a problem with is the fact that I just do not see how
>   this works?

This will not work the way it is drawn, on both sides of the rectifier the voltage is positive. There is no way for current transfer to happen in this type of situation.

In circuit version B adding the resistors does nothing for the voltage on the terminals.

To understand and draw correct diagrams with rectifiers it helps to draw the two modes that the current can follow:
[image]
Source: [Electronics and Communications](http://www.electronicsandcommunications.com/2013/04/)

A rectifier could function like a xor function, but you have to keep track of all four situations. Lets say the rectifier has terminals A and B and the output would be the difference between the + and - terminals. So yes you are correct, it does function like a xor gate (except you'll have the diode voltage drop included)

Rectifier:
1) A- 0V B- 0V Output- 0V
2) A- 0V B-12V Output-12V
3) A-12V B- 0V Output-12V
4) A-12V B-12V Output- 0V

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I should have specified that we are talking about DC voltage here. So, I see what you are saying. I just still have the question of what actually causes the voltage at output to be 0V when both inputs are 12V (condition 3)? I'm wanting to actually understand what's going on to make it function that way?

Comment: Current can only flow if the voltage is lower somewhere else in the circuit. If there are two nodes in a circuit next to each other at the same voltage, zero current can flow between them

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpu5wQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note using 12V here you get the 20mA thru a 3V LED but all R's must be rated for 500mW even LED is only using 60mW.  Not very efficient.