# Choosing "pull down" resistors for automotive diode logic XOR gate

Tags: resistors, diodes, logic-gates, bridge-rectifier

Thanks to some members on here I finally managed to understand how a bridge rectifier can be used as a diode logic XOR gate in an automotive application. Now I'm trying to figure out how to select the "pull down" resistors. The bridge rectifiers I'm looking at are all rated at over 100V peak reverse voltage and 10A or more forward current, so I'm pretty sure they should be fine. But what I don't know is how to figure out an appropriate rating for the resistors. Thank you for any help!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNYPDr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm not worried about R3, just R1 and R2.

Comment: Or I'm just thinking too hard or over simplifying. It just occurred to me that whatever resistors I used would end up being in series with the LED when it is on and that would determine the appropriate rating? Maybe...

Comment: I dont know who said what to hurt your feelings. I did not see anything that matches what you said. But I understand and dont be too sensitive to critical statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate question  [Help me understand XOR gate with diode logic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/322156/help-me-understand-xor-gate-with-diode-logic/322168#322168)  with "wrong" answer selected (lol)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpu5wQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I did not see that response until after I posted this question. I have been chastised before and down voted for asking a follow up question within a question instead of asking a new one. And, I did not chose the wrong answer, I chose the one that helped me understand the why and how that I asked in the other question. I will accept this one here because it has answered what I asked here.